# Trying to upload my project to pythonanywhere.com and getting errors

Tags: python, django, react-redux, pythonanywhere

I need help. I'm trying to upload my project to pythonanywhere.com and getting errors. Who knows the solution?

I tried to google and find a solution to the problem. But the results were in vain, like Sisyphean labor
[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOdzp.png)

Comment: Please post all code and error messages as plain text.  Images are hard to work with.

Comment: Also, That's not full error message. There should be useful hint on the end.